# Return dict indexed by primary key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a realy simple API Endpoint which return a list of `MyModel`.

views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def index(request):
    myModel = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer = MyModelSerializer(myModel, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2']
```

Now I'd like to return a serialized dictionary of models indexed by the primary key (which is a CharField).

```
{
    'pk1':{
           'field1': 'fo',
           'field2': 'bar',
     },
    'pk2':{
           'field1': 'fobar',
           'field2': 'foo',
     }
}
```

[EDIT] As requested, here is the model:

```
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
    field1 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    field2 = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

Comment: Share a sample of the model

Comment: Done, of course everything is fictitious and simplified.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `to_representation` method in your serializer

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        return {instance.pk: ret}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a custom ListSerializer that will return a dictionary.

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers

class DictSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data
        return [
            (item.id, self.child.to_representation(item)) for item in iterable
        ]

    @property
    def data(self):
        ret = super(DictSerializer, self).data
        return serializers.ReturnDict(ret, serializer=self)
```

Then you'll have to specify that your ModelSerializer should use this custom when many=True.  You do this by setting the list_serializer_class in the Meta of your ModelSerializer.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2']
        list_serializer_class = DictSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be efficient following his [Gabriel Muj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48019240/3927762) solution is better but will not provide what you want out of the box.  His solution will provide output like:

```py
[{
    'pk1': {
      'field1': 'fo',
      'field2': 'bar',
    }
  },
  {
    'pk2': {
      'field1': 'fobar',
      'field2': 'foo',
    }
  }
]
```

First change the serializer according to His solution:

```py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        return {instance.pk: ret}
```

But to get what you asked you need to use ChainMap from collections. Now you need to change your views like this:

```py
from collections import ChainMap

@api_view(['GET'])
def index(request):
    myModel = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer = MyModelSerializer(myModel, many=True)
    data_dict = dict(ChainMap(*serializer.data))

    return Response(data_dict)
```

For this snippet you need to make sure its python 3.3+ . This will provide good performance. While optimizing my code I have found this solution is less heavy.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the query set. In your `index` view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def index(request)
    data = dict()
    for element in MyModel.objects.all():
        dict[element.id] = {'field1': element.field1, 'field2': element.field2}
    return Response(data)
```

Comment: it is the serialization which blocks me

Comment: Can you just not use the serializer object? I've updated the answer.